# How to sort a list by modulo in a one-liner

Tags: python

I need to write in one line a code that would display a sorted array on which negative elements are taken modulo (they are displayed negative on the screen)

Example:

```
data = [4, -30, 100, -100, 123, 1, 0, -1, -4]
output:
[0, 1, -1, 4, -4, -30, 100, -100, 123]
```

```
data = [4, -30, 100, -100, 123, 1, 0, -1, -4]

def is_module(x):
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

print(sorted([data[x] for x in range(len(data)) if is_module(data[x])]))
```

I expected this:

```
    [0, 1, -1, 4, -4, -30, 100, -100, 123]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can sort the list with `abs` as the key function:

```
sorted(data, key=abs)
```

This returns:

```
[0, 1, -1, 4, -4, -30, 100, -100, 123]
```

If you want the negative values to be always ordered after positive values of the same absolute values, you can use a function that returns a 2-tuple of the value's absolute value and negative value instead:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda n: (abs(n), -n))
```

Comment: This does produce the desired output for the input given, but I'm a little worried because the result is sensitive to the starting arrangement of numbers. For example, `sorted([2, -1, 1], key=abs)` and `sorted([2, 1, -1], key=abs)` return differently ordered results, even though the lists contain all the same numbers.

Comment: True. I've updated my answer to account for such a possibility then.